# Trouble getting a function argument as a string to use in the function itself

Tags: javascript, html, function

Title may be very confusing, but let me explain. I have a list of pictures on the left and I added an `onclick` function on all of them to display the picture and some info on the right side. I guess it's some kind of thumbnails on the left and a larger version on the right, only one at a time though. So I put the left pictures in the container using an array of all the file names and a loop:

```
var ancients = [
    "hunter",
    "strangling-vines",
    "quicksand",
    "earthquake",
    "eruption"
]
var ancients_list = "";
for (i = 0; i < ancients.length; i++) { 
    ancients_list += '<a id="' + ancients[i] + '"><img src="img/the-ancients/' + ancients[i] + '.png" height="120px" onclick="ancients(' + ancients[i] + ')" /></a>';
}
document.getElementById("ancients").innerHTML = ancients_list;
```

The `ancients` function looks like this:

```
function ancients(name) {
    var name2 = String(name);
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="img/the-ancients/' + name2 + '.png" />';
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'the name of this piece is ' + name2;
}
```

This doesn't work at all. I can call the function in the HTML file with a button and have the name argument be a number and then it does show up on the right side; it's like the name argument I try to define in the loop doesn't want to be inserted in the image/text on the right side. In the eventual HTML page, the image line works fine; I get this:

```
<img src="img/the-ancients/hunter.png" height="120px" onclick="ancients(hunter)">
```

I tried many things but I just don't know and can't find what I'm doing wrong, I'm thinking something about the parameter and argument of the `ancients` function but I'm really not sure.

Also, when I put `typeof name2` in the info section, it returns as `String`.

Comment: Add quotes around the values, i.e. onclick="ancients('hunter')" should do the trick.  Of course, you have to do that when you build the images.

Comment: If hunter is supposed to be a string (IE the actual value, not a variable), do what @Will said. I don't see how that could not be the case. `hunter` is `undefined` otherwise.

Comment: Do this: ancients_list += '<a id="' + ancients[i] + '"><img src="img/the-ancients/' + ancients[i] + '.png" height="120px" onclick="ancients(\'' + ancients[i] + '\')" /></a>';

Comment: Thanks, that did it! @Will

Answer (score 2):

because

```
onclick="ancients(' + ancients[i] + ')"
```

renders as

```
onclick="ancients(hunter)"
```

so your code is looking for a variable hunter, not a string. You need to add quotes around your string.

```
onclick="ancients(\'' + ancients[i] + '\')"
```

now it will render as

```
onclick="ancients('hunter')"
```

Now if the string contains a `'` it will fail.

Ideally you would just use data attributes and add unobtrusive event handlers.

```js
function ancientsFnc(name) {
  var name2 = String(name);
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'the name of this piece is ' + name2;
}

var ancients = [
  "hunter",
  "strangling-vines",
  "quicksand",
  "earthquake",
  "eruption"
]
var ancients_list = "";
for (i = 0; i < ancients.length; i++) {
  ancients_list += '<a href="#" id="' + ancients[i] + '">' + ancients[i] + '</a>';
}

var ancientElem = document.getElementById("ancients");
ancientElem.innerHTML = ancients_list;
ancientElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.srcElement;
  ancientsFnc(elem.id);
  return false;
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="ancients"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help! I didn't know how to add yet another ' to that line of code so now I know it can be done with \'. Thanks again!